# How to close (or merge) two stack overflow accounts created by mistake?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

**tl;dr:**  Please merge [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846778/stephen-bissell) into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798615/steve-bissell), I want to retain the second account

---

I've manage to create two accounts, just like the question "How to merge two Stack Overflow accounts?" and from looking at that, it looks like I need admin intervention....
one account is *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846778/stephen-bissell)* account I'm using to ask the question, logged in via facebook, created today.

The other - the one I'm really interested in - is the one [I created to answer a question, the user id associated with it is 798615](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798615/steve-bissell) - ok, I only answered one question, but I'd kind of like to keep the account, or merge it into the facebook one. I can't remember what (if any) password I created for that account.

I'm pretty sure I used the same email address - my personal one, which is a hotmail account.
If an admin person can help me out, that would be great!